# How can I vectorize these nested loops in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, vectorization, pytorch

I am trying to vectorize the following:

```
n = torch.zeros_like(x)
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    for j in range(x.shape[1]):
        for k in range(x.shape[2]):
            n[i, j, k] = p[i, x[i, j, k], j, k]
```

I tried doing something like

```
n = p[:, x, ...]
```

but I just get an error that I ran out of memory, which isn't very helpful. I think the problem with this is that instead of getting the value of x at the correct index it is trying to index the entirety of x, but I am not sure how I would go about fixing that if that is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a perfect use-case for [broadcasted fancy indices](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing). [`np.ogrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ogrid.html) is a valuable tool here, or you can manually reshape your ranges:

```
i, j, k = np.ogrid[:x.shape[0], :x.shape[1], :x.shape[2]]
n = p[i, x, j, k]
```

This black magic works because the index into `ogrid` returns three arrays that broadcast into the same shape as `x`. Therefore the final extraction from `p` will have that shape. The indexing is trivial after that. Another way to write it is:

```
i = np.arange(x.shape[0]).reshape(-1, 1, 1)
j = np.arange(x.shape[1]).reshape(1, -1, 1)
k = np.arange(x.shape[2]).reshape(1, 1, -1)
n = p[i, x, j, k]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have had similar problems before and always thought there must be something in numpy to do this but I never knew what to search for. Now that I know what I am looking for there is a plethora of documentation.

Comment: @nicememe420. Honestly, fancy indexing is a pain in my rump and I try to stay away from it as much as I can. Slices are much nicer to work with, IMO, even when you have to get weird with broadcasting. Always good to have a full complement of tools though.